# Chrome extension won't open a new window when button is clicked

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension

I followed a few guides on stackoverflow and even copying the code exactly from this [page](http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jwinopen.htm) exactly. When I press the button on the page, it works fine; however, when I add it to my project, the window does not pop up. Is there like some setting that I need to configure for it to popup?

Answer (score 1):

To open new [window](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows) in chrome extension, you have to create a window using chrome extension [window.create](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-create) API. Now to use this API you have to add tabs permission in your manifest.json

```
 {
    "name": "My extension",
    ...
    "permissions": ["tabs"],
    ...
  }
```

Still your popup script or your content script does not have permission to use this API directly, you have to first tell the background script to open a new window.

**In your popup script**

In your button click handler:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({message: "openWindow"});
```

Now add a listener in your background script that will listen to the events and if it will get the message "openWindow", it will create a new window like this:

**In background script**

```
 chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (req, sender, res) {
     if(req.message == "openWindow"){
         var path = "https://www.stackoverflow.com"; /*path/to/page or web URL*/
         openCustomWindow(path);
     }
 });


 function openCustomWindow(uri){
    var winObj = {
        url: uri,
        width: 600,
        height: 600,
        left: Math.round(screen.width / 2 - 400 / 2),
        top: Math.round(screen.height / 2 - 400 / 2),
        focused: true,
        type: "normal",
        state: "normal"
    };
    chrome.windows.create(winObj);
 }
```

You can see window properties in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#type-Window)